# Export an array to a CSV file in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, export-to-csv

Given a (2d) array `A` how to export it into a CSV file with Julia?

Back in the older versions, I would write

```
writecsv( "FileName.csv",  A);
```

which would dump the array A into the given file. This, however, does not work in version >= 1.0. After some googling, I also tried to use the CSV module doing

```
f = open("test.csv", "a+");
CSV.write(f, A; delim = ',')
```

but this throws an error

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: no default `Tables.rows` implementation for type: Array{Int64,2}
```

(my array A was of type Int64).

Does anyone have a working solution for this most trivial question?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to load `DelimitedFiles` module and now only `writedlm` function is supported.

So in order to write an array as CSV file use:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> writedlm( "FileName.csv",  A, ',')
```

To get the same result with CSV.jl package use:

```
julia> using CSV, Tables

julia> CSV.write("FileName.csv",  Tables.table(A), writeheader=false)
```

as `Matrix` does not support Tables.jl interface so you need to wrap it with `Tables.table`.

Comment: Not sure if this is always needed, but note that you may have to add the `:auto` argument, as in `DataFrame(A, :auto)`.  Bogumił, is this the newer practice? Thanks. Quote: "`DataFrame` constructor from a `Matrix` requires passing :auto as a second argument to automatically generate column names: `DataFrame(matrix, :auto)`"

Comment: yes, now `:auto` is required. I updated the answer with the currently recommended practice - `Tables.table` which does not copy.

Comment: When I try this fix I get the error message ```MethodError: no method matching table(::Array{Int64, 3})```. Is this because I can't write a 3d array to a .csv file? Is here any way in julia to write a 3d array to a .csv file?